# Pyspark: Convert date from string format (20220124) to date format

Tags: date, pyspark, timestamp

In a spark dataframe, I will like to convert date column, "Date"  which is in string format (eg. 20220124) to 2022-01-24 and then to date format using python.

df_new= df.withColumn('Date',to_date(df.Date, 'yyyy-MM-dd'))

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with to_date function which gets the input col and format of your date.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn('date', F.to_date('date', 'yyyyMMdd'))
```